# Spark performance advantage vs. Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am hearing that Spark has an advantage over hadoop due to spark's in-memory computation. However, one of the obvious problems is not all the data can fit into one computers memory. So is Spark then limited to smaller datasets. At the same time, there is the notion of spark cluster. So I am not following the purported advantages of spark over hadoop MR.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop MapReduce has been the mainstay on Hadoop for batch jobs for a long time. However, two very promising technologies have emerged, [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/), which is a low-density SQL engine for self-service data exploration and [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/), which is a general-purpose compute engine that allows you to run batch, interactive and streaming jobs on the cluster using the same unified frame. Let's dig a little bit more into Spark.

To understand Spark, you have to understand really three big concepts.

1. First is **RDDs**, the resilient distributed data sets. This is really a representation of the data that's coming into your system in an object format and allows you to do computations on top of it. RDDs are resilient because they have a long lineage. Whenever there's a failure in the system, they can recompute themselves using the prior information using lineage.
2. The second concept is **transformations**. Transformations is what you do to RDDs to get other resilient RDDs. Examples of transformations would be things like opening a file and creating an RDD or doing functions like printer that would then create other resilient RDDs.
3. The third and the final concept is **actions**. These are things which will do where you're actually asking for an answer that the system needs to provide you, for instance, count or asking a question about what's the first line that has Spark in it. The interesting thing with Spark is that it does lazy elevation which means that these RDDs are not loaded and pushed into the system as in when the system encounters an RDD but they're only done when there is actually an action to be performed.

One thing that comes up with RDDs is that when we come back to them being that they are resilient and in main memory is that how do they compare with distributed shared memory architectures and most of what are familiar from our past? There are a few differences. Let's go with them in a small, brief way. First of all, writes in RDDs are core of Spark. They are happening at an RDD level. Writes in distributor-shared memory are typically fine-grained. Reads and distributor-shared memory are fine-grained as well. Writes in RDD can be fine or course-grained.

The second piece is recovery. What happens if there is a part in the system, how do we recover it? Since RDDs build this lineage graph if something goes bad, they can go back and recompute based on that graph and regenerate the RDD. Lineage is used very strongly in RDDs to recovery. In distributor-shared memories we typically go back to check-pointing done at intervals or any other semantic check-pointing mechanism. Consistency is relatively trivial in RDDs because the data underneath it is assumed to be immutable. If, however, the data was changing, then consistency would be a problem here. Distributor-shared memory doesn't make any assumptions about mutability and, therefore, leaves the consistency semantics to the application to take care of.

At last let's look at the benefits of Spark:

- Spark provides full recovery using lineage.
- Spark is optimized in making computations as well as placing the computations optimally using the directory cyclic graph.
- Very easy programming paradigms using the transformation and actions on RDDs as well as a ready-rich library support for machine learning, graphics and recently data frames.

At this point a question comes up. If Spark is so great, does Spark actually replace Hadoop? The answer is clearly no because Spark provides an application framework for you to write your big data applications. However, it still needs to run on a storage system or on a no-SQL system.

Answer (score 2):

`Spark` is never limited to smaller `dataset` and its not always about `in-memory`computation. `Spark` has very good number higher `APIS` . `Spark` can process the in `GB` as well. In my realtime experience i have used Spark to handle the streaming application where we usually gets the data in `GB/Hour` basic . And we have used `Spark` in `Telecommunication` to handle bigger `dataset` as well . Check this [RDD Persistence](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) how to accommodate bigger `datasets`.

Answer (score 2):

In case of real world problem we can't solve them just by one MapReduce program which is having a Mapper class and a reducer class, We mostly need to build a **pipeline**. A pipeline will consists of multiple stages each having MapReduce program , and out put of one stage will be fed to one or multiple times to the subsequent stages. And this is a pain because of the amount of IO it involves.

In case of MapReduce there are these Map and Reduce tasks subsequent to which there is a synchronization barrier and one needs to preserve the data to the disc. This feature of MapReduce framework was developed with the intent that in case of failure the jobs can be recovered but the drawback to this is that, it does not leverage the memory of the Hadoop cluster to the maximum. And this becomes worse when you have a iterative algorithm in your pipeline. Every iteration will cause significant amount of Disk IO.

So in order to solve the problem , Spark introduced a new Data Structure called **RDD** . A DS that can hold the information like how the data can be read from the disk and what to compute. Spark also provided easy programming paradigm to create pipeline(**DAG**) by transforming RDDs . And what you get it a series of RDD which knows how to get the data and what to compute.

Finally when an Action is invoked Spark framework internally optimize the pipeline , group together the portion that can be executed together(map phases), and create a final optimized execution plan from the logical pipeline. And then executes it. It also provides user the flexibility to select the data user wanted to be cached. Hence spark is able to achieve near about 10 to 100 times faster batch processing than MapReduce.

Answer (score 2):

Spark advantages over hadoop.

1. As spark tasks across stages can be executed on same executor nodes, the time to spawn the Executor is saved for multiple task.
2. Even if you have huge memory, MapReduce can never make any advantage of caching data in memory and using the in memory data for subsequent steps.
3. Spark on other hand can cache data if huge JVM is available to it. Across stages the inmemory data is used.
4. In Spark task run as threads on same executor, making the task memory footprint light.
5. In MapReduce the Map of reduce Task are processes and not threads.
6. Spark uses efficient serialization format to store data on disk.

Follow this for detail understanding http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/understanding-spark-through-map-reduce/